# Can't find package on Anaconda Navigator. What to do next?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, anaconda, pulp

I am trying to install "pulp" module in Anaconda Navigator's Environment tabs. But when I search in "All" packages I can't find it. It happened with other packages too.

[image]

Is there any way to install my package to the desired environment?

I tried to install it by opening a terminal in the environment, but I see that afterwards it won't show up in the list.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I add a channel via "Channels" but still cannot find additional packages:|

Answer (score 31):

1. Click *Open Terminal* from environment.

   [image: open]
2. Execute `conda install (package-name)` in terminal mode. (The image below shows the installation of a package named `Keras`.)

   [image: execute]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for A2A

1. Open "Anaconda Navigator"
2. Navigate to "Environments"
3. Select your environment where the package needs to be installed
4. Click on the "play/pause" button present on the environment name
5. Click "Open terminal" from your environment
6. In terminal type "conda install (package-name)"

**Added instructions**
1. If the package is not available in any of the Anaconda Repository then type the following:
 "pip install (package name)"

Answer (score 2):

Download tar.gz file of the package (in your case, pulp) from [here](https://pypi.python.org/) and follow the accepted answer of [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156080/installing-modules-to-anaconda-from-tar-gz).