# Installing modules to Anaconda from .tar.gz

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

When I want to install modules to Anaconda, I run `conda install`. However, now I have a `.tar.gz` file and want to install this. How to do?

Comment: did you try `conda install <pkg.tar>`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, I'm describing one here, which should be relatively straight forward, even if your default `python` variable is not anaconda's.

1. Check what is your desired anaconda environment (if you're not sure what does this mean, it probably means that you are using root, the default environment)
2. Run: `conda info --envs` to see the path where your environment is installed
3. Go to that path, and find the absolute path to python.exe, for example:
   `"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe"`
4. Now, run the following command:

`<absolute path to python.exe> -m pip install <path to tar.gz>`

for example:

`C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install c:\mymodule\great.tar.gz`

Note that `<path to tar.gz>` can be relative, absolute and even an online link.

Comment: Just an addition for the noobs in python like me. If you use Anaconda, replace 'pip' to 'conda'

Comment: Edit: Actually, might be not true. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @FloridaMan It depends where the tar.gz file comes from.

Comment: It still looks for the package in the repos. Adding --offline field with conda also does not help.I am also trying to do a local install without needing internet connection.

Comment: why didn't you suggest `conda install <pkg.tar>`?

Comment: what if my package comes from here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda/#/

Answer (score 19):

It depends on where your archive comes from:

- If you got it from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), you need to install it using `pip`:

```
pip install package.tar.gz
# Or:
python -m pip install package.tar.gz
```

- If you got it from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge), you need to use `conda`:

```
conda install package.tar.gz
```

---

If you have multiple python installations, you may need to specify absolute path to the python/conda executable.

Note that the archive files on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) are usually very different:

- [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) archives contain source files, so you may need to build the package in order to install it, which may requires external dependencies;
- [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) are architecture-specific and contains pre-built package, which are much less likely to require external dependencies.

If you already have a working Anaconda distribution, I would encourage you to get archives from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) instead of [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Comment: I just tried installing numpy this way. It doesn't work for me. It seems like `conda install package.tar.gz` does not grab any dependencies.

Comment: Here's some more info about it https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1884

Comment: And how would I know if it is pypi or conda-forge, if the URL is e.g.,
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/dal/files?sort=downloads&version=2021.5.0
as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432492/conda-update-conda-cannot-download-a-few-packages)?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio If it's from the anaconda registry, it's a conda package, so `conda install`.

Comment: I guess that is even if not from `conda-forge`.
Perhaps it is useful to clarify this point in the answer...

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do :

```
Q:\anaconda3\Scripts>conda install q:\quandl-3.4.4-py37_0.tar.bz2

Downloading and Extracting Packages

########################################################################################### 
#################################################################### | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

Q:\anaconda3\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a PSA please don't use `conda install <pkg.tar>` when updating python from a tar.bz. This has the potential to break Anaconda.

Comment: Comment, I lack credit to post it as such. I only added it as an answer to prevent others from following the general comment at the top of the thread. I'l gladly remove it if you know a way for me / someone else to add it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda and downloaded the package from Anaconda Cloud, then you can place your "package.tar.bz2" files in the path shown in Anaconda prompt (Eg. C:\Users) and type in the following command in Anaconda Prompt

conda install package.tar.bz2

I believe it will work for .tar.gz files too.