# how do you install pyspark from tar file for anaconda distribution?

Tags: python, pyspark, anaconda

I need to install pyspark for anaconda. My machine does not have internet connection hence, this wont work. It times out.

```
./conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

I also tried

```
./conda install --offline <psyapark.tar>
```

it tries to go to the internet. I dont get this

I have the the source file:

```
pyspark-2.3.1.tar
```

How can I install this tar file under anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
./conda install pyspark-2.3.1.tar
```

I also found this answer which shows you how to install to the anaconda environment using pip: [installing modules to Anaconda from .tar.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156080/installing-modules-to-anaconda-from-tar-gz)

Hope this helps.