# How to install Chromedriver in Anaconda without using pip or conda cmd

Tags: python, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver

How to install chromedriver in anaconda without using Conda or Pip cmd. Both these options doesn't working in my office network.

Please suggest direct installation method using the .tar.bz2 file downloaded from Anaconda cloud. Please let me know the method in detail as I am new to this.

Comment: The question is why those do not work in your environment. What does not work? Download fails because of a rule? A proxy needs to be configured? You don't have admin permissions on the computer?

Comment: I have the admin rights. Yet  when I tried using conda commands in Anaconda prompt to install packages it fails. The same with pip. The network doesn't allow the installation I believe. When i try it with my personal laptop at home everythiing works fine. It is just the office system that doesn't allow installation using conda and pip

Comment: It shows 'Solving environment: failed'

Comment: Finally this is what i did to install packages directly to anaconda.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167575/9994640