# How to use only .tar.bz2 packages when installing conda package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

In my development environment I am trying to install some packages from an artifactory private repository to my conda environment. I'm trying to explicitly use only the `.tar.bz2` file instead of `.conda` packages as I keep getting a 404 error when trying to pull `.conda` packages. However, when I'm trying to create an environment, conda is still trying to use `.conda` packages instead of its `.tar.bz2` equivalent.

I've tried modifying the `.condarc` so that I've set `use_only_tar_bz2` to `true`.
When I ran `conda config --show`, it shows that `use_only_tar_bz2` flag has been set to `true`.

When I run `conda search` against the `.conda` packages I'm trying to install (_libgcc_mutex, libgcc-ng, libstdcss-ng), conda is able to find these packages in the artifactory remotes. However, when I try to install these I get a

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT Found for url artifactory.remote.url
```

The conda version I have is 4.7.12.
The conda-build version I have is 3.18.10.

I would expect that only the `.tar.bz2` file gets pulled from Artifactory when running conda install. However, conda is throwing a 404 error trying to pull the `.conda` package instead of the `.tar.bz2` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

---

You have to visit: [How to install conda modules using .tar.bz2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156080/installing-modules-to-anaconda-from-tar-gz). Here the fact is that, a `.tar.bz2` file tells you that it is an *archive* created with **tar** and compressed with **bzip2**.

Here are simple workarounds Either you can go like this way:

> Add **use_only_tar_bz2: true** to your **.condarc file**. This setting will
>   force conda to use **.tar.bz2** packages only.

```
$ cat .condarc
channel_alias: https://artifactory.xxx.xx/artifactory/api/conda
channels:
  - anaconda-main
use_only_tar_bz2: true
```

If you still find an issue, be sure to run a "`conda clean`" as i think "`conda clean -i` " might be enough. "`conda clean --all`" definitely worked for me.

Or if you want to get only tar.bz2 files then you should specify your command as follows:

> conda install --offline --verbose c:\temp\pytest.tar.bz2

Now, if you unpack that `tar.bz2` file and there's no `info/file`s file in it, then it's not a *conda* package.

Here is an example of installation of `open-cv` module using tar.bz2: For [example](https://www.scivision.dev/conda-low-bandwidth-manual-tar-bz2-install/).
. If you want to learn in detail, you can see [installing conda packages offline](https://support.anaconda.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023861814-Installing-conda-packages-offline-) and also visit reference: [Conda - offline installations / update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577527/conda-offline-install-update).

Comment: Hi Muhammad thanks for the response. I'm currently working on a linux environment and I'm primarily using Conda for installing conda dependencies when creating a virtual environment. I think your answer is with regards to perhaps a different issue?

Comment: You can go like this : `conda install package-name.tar.bz2`

Comment: Well the issue isn't that I'm unable to install .tar.bz2 packages. The issue is that when I'm running conda install, conda is pulling .conda packages instead of .tar.bz2 from my private repositories. I want to force it to use the old file format .tar.bz2 instead of the .conda package format. Sorry if it wasn't clear!

Comment: Have you visited the reference links, in answer ?

Comment: Yes I have. I understand that If I download the packages locally then I can run conda install on a .tar.bz2 package (and by extension I guess .conda packages also). However, I'd rather not have to download each .tar.bz2 package manually and point to that during installation. I'd like to have it so that when running conda install against my private repo that it only pulls down the .tar.bz2 file instead of its .conda equivalent.

Comment: Answer is now optimized. You can re-visit for solution. Add use_only_tar_bz2: true to your .condarc file. This setting will force conda to use .tar.bz2 packages. as above in answer.

Comment: I tried adding use_only_tar_bz2: true to my .condarc but the issue is that it is not working and it is still trying to use the .conda package instead of the .tar.bz2 file.

Answer (score 0):

The [`conda.base.context.Context.use_only_tar_bz2`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.7.12/conda/base/context.py#L662) property for some reason evaluates to `False`.

I can only point that you're setting `use_only_tar_bz2` to `true` in  your configuration file and thus it isn't parsed to its equivalent Python representative value.

It's documented to [use the Python boolean value](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.7.12/docs/source/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.rst#force-conda-to-download-only-tarbz2-packages-use_only_tar_bz2) in configuration that are set to boolean values.

```py
use_only_tar_bz2: True
```