# How do I install packages to Anaconda from locally built tar.gz

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, openpyxl

I want to edit the package openpyxl and reinstall the edited version to anaconda.

I downloaded the source code from here https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/downloads/.

I then edited the source python files I needed to - the edits are shown at the bottom of this page in case it is relevant > https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1237/unable-to-save-wb-with-3d-bar-chart-from

I then used the following command to create the tar file from my edited source code, as explained here https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

I then used the following command to try and install the edited package.

```
conda install openpyxl-3.0.3.tar.gz
```

But conda started looking for the source code online and i got the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167575/5666087 answer your question?

Comment: ah, yeah. I already looked at that but must've skimmed it too quick. That works. Thanks