# How do I rename a python package?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda, openpyxl

I want to customize a python package. I need to be able to install the customized package in anaconda on other machines. This is the method by which i'm installing the customized package in case it's relevant: [How do I install packages to Anaconda from locally built tar.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758716/how-do-i-install-packages-to-anaconda-from-locally-built-tar-gz)

However i would also like to rename the package. For example if i wanted to edit openpyxl, i want my edited package to be called openpyxl_edit. However the name openpyxl is used in multiple places throughout the original package source code.

Is it likely that i have to rename openpyxl to openpyxl_edit in all of the occurrences in all of the source files in the entire package? Is there an easier way of changing the name of a package?

Comment: If you're using PyCharm, there is a cool 'refactor' feature that changes all instances in code for you.

Comment: I haven't actually used PyCharm, i use Spyder. Maybe I'll give PyCharm a go then and see if it helps. thanks