# pip has problems with metadata

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the `win32core` module using pip, but it keeps displaying warnings about the package/wheel metadata not matching with the filename (inconsistent version).

Here's a snippet of the text displayed in the command prompt before it goes to download older versions:

```
python -m pip install --no-cache-dir win32core
Collecting win32core
  Downloading win32core-221.28.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 2.2 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/
0a6e0b2e201c76ccd3cda1f97bd64d45daa2b899b50e541962748ec5bc9f5d/
win32core-221.28.tar.gz#
sha256=e805548ccde99a3f36931d3eef72cfaaa5dace4288393af898c96f92c1fe5f9e (from https://pypi.org/simple/win32core/).
Requested win32core from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/
24/0a/6e0b2e201c76ccd3cda1f97bd64d45daa2b899b50e541962748ec5bc9f5d/win32core-221.28.tar.gz#
sha256=e805548ccde99a3f36931d3eef72cfaaa5dace4288393af898c96f92c1fe5f9e
has inconsistent version: filename has '221.28', but metadata has '0.0.0'
```

As I've encountered this before, how should I go about installing the module correctly? (I'm on Python 3.9.1)

Comment: This problem happened on my device as well, so it must be on the server side (www.pythonhosted.com)

Comment: @Arandomcoder not really, something is broken in `setuptools` or `pip`... I'm running now: `pip install -U pip` and getting: `(...)  has inconsistent version: filename has '22.1.2', but metadata has '22.1.2'` and `pip` goes into a download loop trying older and older versions... Dependencies are NP-complete... Ther scr***d up! I want the old "dumb" `pip` back!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pip changed rules in the version resolver, it is more strict now.

See discussions :

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9186

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9203

Try using :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver <your_package>
```

Comment: Using --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver will just crash pip:

File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: @RubenKelevra Thank for the info, but 3.10 has seen several changes as well. Anyway, packages should be maintained or backward compatibility should be ensured.

Comment: It was specifically the `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` option that solved this problem for me (for a different package with the same metadata error).

Comment: I still get the warning when I run this command itself!. `WARNING: Skipping /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pycparser-2.21-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'`

Comment: @Dr.jacky Some RC packages on GitHub may not have the final metadata set correctly, hence the weird behavior. Contact the package maintainer.

Comment: @Dr.jacky For me the solution was to manually delete the offending empty files/directories.

Comment: @WayToDoor's solution was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

If you have an issue like this, it might be due to empty directories in your site-packages folder. The following command will fix that :

```
find /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages -empty -type d -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this problem with Anaconda Powershell. Downloaded the package and provided pip with the exact path.

(Look [Installing modules to Anaconda from .tar.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156080/installing-modules-to-anaconda-from-tar-gz))