# I'm unable to install some specific libraries via pip install

Tags: python, pip

I've been trying to install the gym library via `pip install gym`
I get the following error

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/86/3f5467531428b6ce6f3c12d3121b4304d2ea1536a50775a4df036add37b8/gym-0.23.1.tar.gz#sha256=d0f9b9da34edbdace421c9442fc9205d03b8d15d0fb451053c766cde706d40e0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/gym/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Requested gym==0.23.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/86/3f5467531428b6ce6f3c12d3121b4304d2ea1536a50775a4df036add37b8/gym-0.23.1.tar.gz#sha256=d0f9b9da34edbdace421c9442fc9205d03b8d15d0fb451053c766cde706d40e0 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.23.1', but metadata has '0.23.1'
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gym==0.23.1
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gym==0.23.1
```

pip then defaults to trying to install previous versions 0.23.0, 0.22.0 and so on.
I get the following warning for all versions and none installs.

```
request gym from <link> has inconsistent version: filename has '0.9.0', but metadata has '0.9.0'
```

After some Googling for similar errors, I tried updating pip `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`
but I get the same problem with version mismatch, and it tries to install old versions of pip and fails.

I'm on Python 3.10.4 and pip 21.0 under Arch Linux.

edit: The same problem happens to any package I try to install with pip.

Comment: Sometimes the actual modules you're looking for aren't installed by there name for example

Comment: ```win32api``` is installed by ```pip install pywin32```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074684/pip-has-problems-with-metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10929).

The problem seems to be caused by the `python-pip` package under Arch Linux.

One possible way to fix it:

```
sudo pacman -Rncs python-pip
python -m ensurepip
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot figure out pip use git

```
git clone https://github.com/openai/gym
cd gym
pip install -e .
```

Comment: This should work, but the problem is that this also happen with other libraries besides gym.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with an upgrade option to install the latest without cache since looks that the latest version is stable:

```
pip install gym -U --no-cache-dir
```

> -U, --upgrade Upgrade all packages to the newest available version

> --no-cache-dir Disable the cache

If this won't help you can try to install using legacy version resolver (as per https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9203):

```
pip install gym -U --no-cache-dir --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Comment: Disabling the cache does not solve the issue.

The second command returns an error:
`
ERROR: Exception:
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/specifiers.py", line 728, in contains
    item = parse(item)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 49, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
`