# cant upload project to Pypi using twine, missing METADATA file in wheel

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am trying to upload a project to pypi, I have followed every step in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIF3LaRqgXo till 25:00 but I dont seem to be able to `twine upload dist/*` because every time I try it, it gives me this back

(the real module name I replaced with '[modulename]' in this question)

```
 400 Wheel '[modulename]-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl' does not contain the required METADATA file: [modulename]-0.0.1.dist-info/METADATA
```

I have looked online but couldn't find a solution anywhere.
When looking online it refers me to [pip has problems with metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074684/pip-has-problems-with-metadata) but it is not what I need as I want to upload my project to Pypi, not pip install a project from it.

So my question would be:  How do I auto-generate a METADATA file? Did I do something wrong in any of the previous steps?

Comment: The video tutorial is from 3 years ago. Please consult official packaging guide for current info https://packaging.python.org/ Especially because no one is gonna watch a whole yt video just to see what steps you did.

Comment: I have removed your previous [Edit] suley. Please do not add solutions to your question, we have a dedicated answer area for such things.

Comment: Please don't expect us to watch 25 minutes of video and then guess what you actually did and where you could have done something different than the video. Always make your question self-contained, i.e., a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the youtube vid is outdated.
It uses (only) setup.py instead of the current standard of using both `setup.py` aswell as `pyproject.toml` file. Thanks to @h4z3 for referring me to the source site: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/