# How to download opencv-python library in Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, anaconda

I know I can download **opencv-python** using *pip* on my computer but I'm running an Anaconda server using Anaconda Navigator to run a python script. Do I need to install opencv-python via the Navigator or is it enough to download it on your machine via *pip*?

If not, how can I download opencv-python via the Anaconda navigator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find package on Anaconda Navigator. What to do next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299726/cant-find-package-on-anaconda-navigator-what-to-do-next)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:
On the left panel of Navigator, there is a line called "Environments". Change to "Not installed" and search "opencv". Then press Apply on the bottom right of the window.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to install opencv-python via the Navigator or is it enough to download it on your machine via pip

Both `pip` and `conda` can be used to install python packages to your distribution, so using one or the other will install a package to your distribution, but there is some [caution](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) when mixing the two.

---

Coming to your specific package:

`opencv-python` is an unofficial collection of `whl`(wheel) files for `opencv`, see the first line of the [README](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python):

```
Unofficial pre-built OpenCV packages for Python.
```

As `whl` files are specific for installing using `pip` there is no way to install `opencv-python` using the `conda` package manager.

However, since it is only a collection of pre-built `opencv` wheels, you can, as the other answer also suggests, search for `opencv` in the anaconda navigator, or simply install using the command line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```